# function vararg parameter for Enum<T> in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, enums, variadic-functions

I have the following Enums where each Enum class implements `RatingValue` interface and each companion object implements `RatingValues<T>` interface

```kotlin
enum class Clarity(override val value: Int) : RatingValue {
        EXCELENT(5),
        VERY_GOOD(4),
        GOOD(3),
        FAIR(2),
        POOR(1);

        companion object : RatingValues<Clarity>
    }

    enum class Colour(override val value: Int) : RatingValue {
        EXCELENT(10),
        VERY_GOOD(8),
        GOOD(6),
        FAIR(4),
        POOR(2);

        companion object : RatingValues<Colour>
    }
```

`RatingValues` interface has `ratings()` method, which is defined as an extention:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> RatingValues<T>.ratings(): List<Int> where T : RatingValue, T : Enum<T> = enumValues<T>().map { it.value }
```

I'd like to implement a method that takes a vararg parameter of `RatingValue` enums which would be callable like this

```kotlin
val cumulativeRating = cumulate(Colour, Clarity)
```

My first idea was to write the following, however that fails since the generic type parameter T for RatingValues is obviously different

```kotlin
private inline fun  <reified T> cumulate(vararg ratings: RatingValues<T>) : List<Int> where T: RatingValue, T : Enum<T>  {
        return ratings
            .map(RatingValues<T>::ratings)
            .fold(listOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)) { x, y -> x.zip(y, Int::plus) }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method which could accept vararg `RatingValues<T>` with different `T` is:

```kotlin
private fun cumulate(vararg ratings: RatingValues<*>): List<Int> {
    return ratings
        .map { it.ratings() }
        .reduce { x, y -> x.zip(y, Int::plus) } //same semantics, but more concise and performant
}
```

The problem is that due to type erasure, information about actual type of `T` would be lost, so it will be reified as `Object` and you'll get rather cryptic runtime error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Object.values()[Ljava/lang/Object;` (in my opinion, compiler shouldn't have compiled this in the first place, but that's not the point).

I'm afraid, you' ll have to define `ratings()` method in the `RatingValues` interface as non-generic and implement it in every enum's companion object to make it work correctly:

```kotlin
interface RatingValues<T> where T : RatingValue, T : Enum<T> {
    fun ratings(): List<Int>
}

inline fun <reified T> RatingValues<T>.ratingsForEnums(): List<Int> where T : RatingValue, T : Enum<T> =
    enumValues<T>().map { it.value }

enum class Clarity(override val value: Int) : RatingValue {
    EXCELENT(5),
    VERY_GOOD(4),
    GOOD(3),
    FAIR(2),
    POOR(1);

    companion object : RatingValues<Clarity> {
        override fun ratings() = ratingsForEnums()
    }
}

enum class Colour(override val value: Int) : RatingValue {
    EXCELENT(10),
    VERY_GOOD(8),
    GOOD(6),
    FAIR(4),
    POOR(2);

    companion object : RatingValues<Colour> {
        override fun ratings() = ratingsForEnums()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an extensive explanation. I think in this case I will rather stick with passing the actual rating list as a parameter to ```cumulate``` as I want to keep the Enum definitions clean (there is actually quite a few more of these enums).  However, this pretty much confirm my suspicion for why it was not possible.